# Auth0 Authentication not working when callbackurl is a directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, auth0

I'm having a hard time finding the right words to google I think. I am integrating Auth0 into a new web site, and I have followed the quick start tutorial for a AS.NET MVC site.

When I set the Allowed Callback to be https://localhost:44334, everything works like a charm. I can log in, I see the cookie created,all of it.

But, when I set the Allowed Callback to be https://localhost:44334/anyFolderHere, I get nothing.  The site redirects to Auth0, I can log in, and I get redirected to the correct location. But no cookie, no auth token, nothing.

I can see in the Auth0 logs that it thinks everything went fine, login successful. I see no errors being thrown in my code, I just get nothing.

The code I have is almost line-for-line from their quick start. I am hesitant to start making changes until I can see it working...

I'm sure I am making a rookie mistake here, but I'm getting frustrated and just can't see past myself.

Here is what I have:

```
public class Startup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure Auth0 parameters
        string auth0Domain = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:Domain"];
        string auth0ClientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientId"];
        string auth0ClientSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientSecret"];
        string auth0RedirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:RedirectUri"];
        string auth0PostLogoutRedirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

        // Enable the Cookie saver middleware to work around a bug in the OWIN implementation
        app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();

        // Set Cookies as default authentication type
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });

        // Configure Auth0 authentication
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Auth0",

            Authority = $"https://{auth0Domain}",

            ClientId = auth0ClientId,
            ClientSecret = auth0ClientSecret,

            RedirectUri = auth0RedirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = auth0PostLogoutRedirectUri,

            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            Scope = "openid profile",

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name"
            },

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
                {
                    if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                    {
                        var logoutUri = $"https://{auth0Domain}/v2/logout?client_id={auth0ClientId}";

                        var postLogoutUri = notification.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postLogoutUri))
                        {
                            if (postLogoutUri.StartsWith("/"))
                            {
                                // transform to absolute
                                var request = notification.Request;
                                postLogoutUri = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + postLogoutUri;
                            }
                            logoutUri += $"&returnTo={ Uri.EscapeDataString(postLogoutUri)}";
                        }

                        notification.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
                        notification.HandleResponse();
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Home")
                },
                "Auth0");
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public void Logout()
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("Auth0");
        }
    }
```

EDIT:  I added event handlers for AuthenticationFailed, AuthorizationCodeReceived, MessageReceived, SecurityTokenReceived and SecurityTokenValidated. Those handles do NOT fire when calling https://{host}/anyFolderHere. However they DO fire when just coming from https://{host}/.

code added, with breakpoints in the debugger at each step.

```
 },AuthenticationFailed = failed =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = received =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    MessageReceived = message =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenReceived = token =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenValidated = validate =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
```

Comment: I can suggest you two things that helped me: 1. install chocoChip - cookie Manager (chrome) and 2. change from localhost to a fake address (app.example.com) set in the /etc/hosts for my localhost ip. Apparently the cookies have some problems with the https and localhost sometimes, so better avoid this. And my question: what path do you set for your cookies?

Comment: I'll take a look at chocoChip, thanks. I can change localhost to a fake address, but the real site, which is published to a domain I own has the exact same problem. I'm just using localhost to reproduce the issue and try and debug.   No path for cookies, I'm trying to make this work, so as few moving parts as possible.